# Debugging com object called from EdgeTransport.exe

Tags: .net, comobject, microsoft-exchange

I am trying to debug a com object that was hooked into the edge transport. I added the pdb file for my com object and trying to debug using the attach process from visual studio. But the breakpoint is never working. I tried to change the type of attaching to process and none of them worked !! do you have any idea what could be happening? do i need pdb to the caller to (edgeTransport) since that i will never have apparently.